# Automatically create test database every week

Tags: sql-server, automation

There is a production db in SQL Server. We still have development on this database and I want to create it's copy in every X day/week/month. Is there any job or something else what can make this on SQL Server?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have backups, you could call [RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) on the development database.  You can do that from a SQL Agent job, or a scheduled task like a powershell script.

The restore wizard itself allows you to script a restore action, which can help to write out the full RESTORE statement.